# How to build Juliet test suite with cov-build tool for analysis through GitHub

Tags: compilation, static-analysis, coverity

I'm a graduate student doing research on static analysis tools and false positives. Part of this work involves checking out the results from Coverity which is available through GitHub. So far I have been unable to use the cov-build tool to compile the code I am working with and I'm stumped. I am working with the Juliet test suite from NIST available here https://samate.nist.gov/SRD/testsuites/juliet/Juliet_Test_Suite_v1.3_for_C_Cpp.zip. It comes with a compile_all.bat file that compiles all the test cases into one monolithic executable on windows.

More specifically this is done through the developers command prompt from Visual Studio 2019. When just the compile_all.bat file is used there are no problems and all the library files and executable are generated. When I use the command `cov-build --dir cov-int compile_all.bat` the C/C++ files are compiled into object files but the cov-build tool hangs and prevents the library file and executable from being created. I have been unable to determine what the problem could be but I have seen other repositories that have managed to get this done so I know it must be possible. Any ideas what the problem could be? My build-log.txt file is far too large to post here but I can supply it on request, thanks for any help!

**More detail:**
The basic directory structure of the Juliet test suite is below. From the compile_all.bat file the for loop calls the batch file for each Common Weakness Enumeration (CWE) subdirectory. This file compiles the files in the directory as well as those in the "testcasesupport" directory then links them.

The whole process starts with the CWE114 subdirectory and all of the files within that directory compile just fine but when the compilation and linking starts for the support files the cov-build tool does not allow the process to continue and just hangs there. Nothing is even written to the build-log.txt file at that point, the last log entry just details the successful compilation of the last file in the CWE114 subdirectory. The contents of the compile_all.bat file and the CWE114.bat file are below also.

To reiterate, the problem is not in the batch files because when I run the compile_all.bat file everything works fine.The hang comes into play only when the cov-build tool is involved in the process. Just trying to give some context here so you fine people can help me get my problem solved, thanks!

```
C  
|  
+-- testcases  
|  |  
|  +-- CWE114  
|     |  
|     +-- testcase1.c  
|     +-- testcase2.cpp  
|     +-- CWE114.bat  
|  
+--testcasesupport  
|  |  
|  +-- io.c  
|  +-- std_thread.c  
|  
+-- compile_all.bat
```

Contents of compile_all.bat:

```
rem NOTE: this batch file is to be run in a Visual Studio command prompt

rem Delete old files
del *.obj
del *.ilk
del *.exe

rem Compile test cases individually
set root=%cd%
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dir testcases\*.bat /b/s`) DO ( 
  cd %%~dpF
  %%F
  lib /out:%root%\%%~nF.lib CWE*.obj
  cd %root% 
)

rem Compile support files
cl /I"testcasesupport" /W3 /MT /GS /RTC1 /bigobj /EHsc /nologo /c "testcasesupport\main.cpp" "testcasesupport\io.c" "testcasesupport\std_thread.c"

rem Link all test cases together 
cl /FeTestcases *.obj CWE*.lib /I"testcasesupport" /W3 /MT /GS /RTC1 /bigobj /EHsc /nologo
```

Contents of CWE114.bat:

```
rem NOTE: this batch file is to be run in a Visual Studio command prompt

rem Delete old files
del *.obj
del *.ilk
del *.exe
del *.pdb

rem Compile files into .obj files in current directory
cl /I"..\..\testcasesupport" /W3 /MT /GS /RTC1 /bigobj /EHsc /nologo /c main.cpp CWE*.cpp CWE*.c ..\..\testcasesupport\io.c ..\..\testcasesupport\std_thread.c
rem Link all .obj file into a exe
cl /FeCWE114 *.obj /I"..\..\testcasesupport" /W3 /MT /GS /RTC1 /bigobj /EHsc /nologo
```

Comment: Suggestion 1: Try removing as much as you can from `compile_all.bat` while preserving the symptom (hanging, in this case).  Suggestion 2: While the build is hung, use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find exactly which process is hung.  Suggestion 3: Try to find the part of build-log.txt around the hang (maybe just the end?) and post that.

Comment: Turns out there was no problem after all. But many thanks to @ScottMcPeak for the help, I never would have figured out what was going on! The cov-build command calls cov-translate.exe after the compilation is done for a CWE subdirectory which sequentially calls cov-emit.exe on each file that was compiled. During this process there is no output to the console so it appears to hang. Each cov-emit.exe calls takes 1-2 seconds and there are 988 files in the CWE114 subdirectory so there is no console output for well over 15 minutes and I was terminating the build after about 10.

Comment: The Process Explorer helped me figure out what was going on behind the scenes and I decided to not terminate the build. Since cov-build appears to run sequentially it will add a tremendous amount of time to my build but it does work. Talk about a great opportunity for multithreading! Only the very patient and committed will benefit from the open-source Coverity GitHub integration.

Comment: Glad you were able to make progress.  I suggest putting the resolution into an answer (self-answers are fine on SO) so other readers know the issue is resolved.  The key here is that `cov-build` is slower than you were expecting, so I suggest including how long the original build took and how long it took with `cov-build`.  That would be a useful data point for any Coverity user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm summarizing the information recorded in comments so people know this question has been answered:

1. There wasn't any problem other than `cov-build` being slower than expected.  (I do not know precisely how much slower in this case, but in my experience a 2-3x slowdown is typical.)
2. Using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) while `cov-build` was running was the key diagnostic step.